# Rotating a matrix to create a spiral order of values

Tags: matlab

How do I rotate a matrix to create a spiral order of values?

For example,

```
12 4 2 
8 3 11
6 7 2
```

I am supposed to to display `12 4 2 11 2 7 6 8 3` but I don't know how to terminate at the 1st row and rotate the function 90 degrees. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please include your research effort (if any) and what you have tried so far! Stackoverflow is not the place to ask somebody else to make your function

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*:

Check the `spiral` function:

> `spiral(n)` is an `n`-by-`n` matrix with elements ranging
>       from `1` to `n^2` in a rectangular spiral pattern.

Use its output to build an index into the original values. You may also need [`sort`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html), as well as [`fliplr`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html) to reverse the order of values.

*See the code after you've given it a try*.

> `x = [12 4 2; 8 3 11; 6 7 2];` 
>  `t = fliplr(spiral(sqrt(numel(x))));` 
>  `[~, ind] = sort(t(:));` 
>  `result = fliplr(x(ind).');`

Answer (score 1):

```
A =[12     4     2;...
     8     3    11;...
     6     7     2];

B=[];

for ii=1:5

B = [B A(1,:)];

A(1,:)=[];

A=rot90(A);

end
B
```

> > > B =
>
> ```
> 12     4     2    11     2     7     6     8     3
> ```